# Does calling an async function within another function make that other function async too?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I wanted to have clarification on this. Let's say I have two functions. One is an async function. If I were to call that async function within another function, would that function call need the await keyword, and therefore the other function must also be an async function too?

That is my mindset of how I approach this. I haven't had any errors thrown before because of this.

Comment: You can use promises explicitly instead of `await`.

Answer (score 3):

> Would that function call need the `await` keyword, and therefore the other function must also be an `async function` too?

No. An `async function` is just a function that always returns a promise, and it's actually pretty indistinguishable from a normal `function` that returns a promise (from the outside).

The `await` keyword is not a modifier for the function call before which it is placed. It's just awaiting a promise *value* that the call is returning, and this works for any other expression. You can also split it apart like `const promise = someFunction(); const result = await promise;`.

Answer (score 3):

A function that uses the `async` keyword:

- Will return a promise that resolves to the value that it `return`s
- Supports the `await` keyword which will let it go to sleep until the promise on the right hand side of the `await` keyword resolves

So given:

```
function async foo() {
    return 27;
}

function bar() {
    const return_value = foo();
}

foo();
```

`foo` will return a promise which resolves to `27`

The `return_value` variable will the value of a promise.

There is no requirement for `bar` to use the `async` keyword unless you want to change it to:

```
const return_value = await foo();
```

… so that `bar` can go to sleep until the promise returned by `foo` resolves to `27` (in which case `return_value` would be `27` instead of being a promise).

Answer (score 0):

No your function that calls the asynch function won't getting through this asynch because the normal calculation goes on. Only the part which waits on the asynch function sleeps as long as it gets an answer from the asynch.

Otherwise the hole programm would stop and wait just on your asynch-answer and with this the asynch wouldn't function.